# How do we do residual analysis for linear mixed effect models (small sample size)?

Tags: mixed-model, residuals

Can anyone please explain me how to do residual analysis for the dataset that has small group size (like two samples per group) and around 10-15 groups in total? Now the errors are correlated within groups, so how should we go about it?
 Also, should we assume that errors are normally distributed for this small size dataset?

Comment: If you really only have two samples per group, could you analyse the differences from each group? Then proceed as for a non-mixed model.

Comment: Sure, but the lmer package shows significant between group variance. Should we just ignore it? Also, what if there are more samples per group? How would we do residual analysis in that case?

Comment: lmer gives you residuals to the fit. You can plot these and check for normality. You can also get the estimated random effects, using ranef(lmer.object) and plot these as well. They should also be normal. With a small data set, you can probably only check for outliers. You especially need to assume normality for a small data.  Any significance tests assume normality in the model errors, or a large enough sample for the maximum likelihood estimates to be approximately normal.

Comment: okay, so the only assumption that lmer package holds for residuals is normality of residuals and not independence, because of group level correlation?